# How to calculate a weighted average in XPath or XQuery?

Tags: xpath, xquery, orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0

I need to calculate a simple weighted average in a XForms form. How can I do that in an elegant and declarative way using XPath and/or XQuery ?

[EDITED] This is the source XML document :

```
<Examens>
    <Examen>
        <ExamenId>1</ExamenId>
        <Coef>1</Coef>
        <Notes>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>100</EleveId>
                <Valeur>4</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>101</EleveId>
                <Valeur>4.2</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>102</EleveId>
                <Valeur>3.8</Valeur>
            </Note>
        </Notes>
    </Examen>
    <Examen>
        <ExamenId>2</ExamenId>
        <Coef>2</Coef>
        <Notes>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>100</EleveId>
                <Valeur>5</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>101</EleveId>
                <Valeur/>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>102</EleveId>
                <Valeur>3.5</Valeur>
            </Note>
        </Notes>
    </Examen>
    <Examen>
        <ExamenId>3</ExamenId>
        <Coef>3</Coef>
        <Notes>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>100</EleveId>
                <Valeur>6</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>101</EleveId>
                <Valeur>5.4</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>102</EleveId>
                <Valeur>2</Valeur>
            </Note>
        </Notes>
    </Examen>
</Examens>
```

The following snippet is correctly displaying the values (= `./Valeur`) and the weight (= `./../../Coef`) :

```
<xforms:repeat nodeset="$currentBranche//Note[EleveId=$currentEleveId]">
     <xforms:output ref="./Valeur"/>
     <xforms:output ref="./../../Coef"/>
</xforms:repeat>
```

BTW, I also need to exclude the nodes for which `Valeur` is an empty string. For example, in the following simple average calculation with the XPath `avg()` function, I got an error ("Cannot convert '' to double") if one node's content is an empty string. This is a problem, because the node exist (it's part of a model instance) and the value is an empty string when the user has not yet entered a value.

```
<xforms:output ref="round(avg($currentBranche//Note[EleveId=$currentEleveId]/Valeur)*100) div 100"/>
```

[EDITED]

The correct calculations are :

If EleveId=100 : weighted average = (1*4+2*5+3*6) / (1+2+3)     = 5.333
If EleveId=101 : weighted average = (1*4.2+3*5.4) / (1+3)       = 5.1
If EleveId=102 : weighted average = (1*3.8+2*3.5+3*2) / (1+2+3) = 2.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In XPath 1.0 Use**:

```
  sum($currentBranche//Note[EleveId=$currentEleveId]/Valeur[number(.)=number(.)])

 div

  count($currentBranche//Note[EleveId=$currentEleveId]/Valeur)
```

**In Xpath 2.0 (XQuery) use**:

```
round(avg($currentBranche//Note[EleveId=$currentEleveId]/Valeur
                                             [number(.)=number(.)])*100
      ) div 100
```

**If all `Valeur` values are guaranteed to be castable as `xs:decimal`, then use:**

```
avg($currentBranche//Note[EleveId=$currentEleveId]/Valeur
                                                 [castable as xs:decimal]
                                                    /xs:decimal(.)
   )
```

In this case there won't be (noticeable) loss of precision and you can use later the `format-number()` function to get the wanted number of digits after the decimal point.

---

**II. Producing "weighted average"**:

**Given the provided XML document**:

```
<Examens>
    <Examen>
        <ExamenId>1</ExamenId>
        <Coef>1</Coef>
        <Notes>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>100</EleveId>
                <Valeur>4</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>101</EleveId>
                <Valeur>4.2</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>102</EleveId>
                <Valeur>3.8</Valeur>
            </Note>
        </Notes>
    </Examen>
    <Examen>
        <ExamenId>2</ExamenId>
        <Coef>2</Coef>
        <Notes>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>100</EleveId>
                <Valeur>5</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>101</EleveId>
                <Valeur/>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>102</EleveId>
                <Valeur>3.5</Valeur>
            </Note>
        </Notes>
    </Examen>
    <Examen>
        <ExamenId>3</ExamenId>
        <Coef>3</Coef>
        <Notes>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>100</EleveId>
                <Valeur>6</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>101</EleveId>
                <Valeur>5.4</Valeur>
            </Note>
            <Note>
                <EleveId>102</EleveId>
                <Valeur>2</Valeur>
            </Note>
        </Notes>
    </Examen>
</Examens>
```

**this XPath 2.0 expression produces the weighted average:**

```
   for $elevId in distinct-values(/*/*/*/*/EleveId)
    return
      round(100*
             (sum(/*/*/*/Note
                    [EleveId eq $elevId
                   and number(Valeur) eq number(Valeur)
                     ]
                      /(Valeur * ../../Coef)
                  )
            div
              sum(/*/*/*/Note
                    [EleveId eq $elevId
                   and number(Valeur) eq number(Valeur)
                    ]
                     /../../Coef
                  )
              )
           )
    div 100
```

**and the expected, correct result is produced**:

```
5.33 5.1 2.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I didn't knew the trick `number(.)=number(.)` to get rid of the empty strings. This solve the second part of my problem, but (my mistake : two questions in one) not the first : how to calculate a **weighted** average, using weights placed at a relative path from the value (./../../Coef) ? I really don't know how to do it with a XPath/XQuery expression.

Comment: @cbosson, You haven't provided any XML document that has element(s) named `Coef`. The answer wouldn't be difficulr if you edit the question and provide the now missing source XML document. Please.

Comment: @cbosson, I added a second part to my answer, showing what I believe is the simplest way to produce a weighted average.

Comment: This is not how a weighted average is calculated. The correct formula would be `sum(/*/num(val*weight))` divided by `sum(/*num/val)`, and should =4 with this example.

Comment: @Flynn1179 You're right in the way you want to calculate the weighted average, but I think the second formula of your answer should be `sum(/*/num/weight)` isn't it? Anyway, thanks for your input !

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I added the source XML and the correct answers for those sample data. It would help me a lot if you could have a look at it !

Comment: Depends what the average is weighted on of course- I'd usually put the 'quantity' first, so I thought they should be weighted on `val`. Reading it again, I probably should have realised it was the other way round.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: In part II, your expected result no longer relates to the example you created, now that you're using the OP's example.

Comment: @Flynn1179, Thanks. Replaced my document with the OP-provided one.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Wow. Still need to learn a few things in XPath... Thank you very much for your help ! Very appreciated.